# Django DRF - How to serialize a list of values (not list of objects)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to serialize this data

```
{ dates : [2020-06-11, 2020-06-12, 2020-06-13 ...], sources : ['Facebook', 'Twitter'...], count: [{'date': 2020-06-11, source: 'Facebook', 'count': 4}, ....]
```

How am I able to serialize the dates, and sources? It comes in a list and is not a list of objects, but merely a list of values. I have only serialized lists of objects before using the many=True keyword, but have never tried serializing a list of values. Do let me know how I am supposed to approach this, thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To serialize a list of values you have to use `serializers.ListField` with child of your value type.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    sources = serializer.ListField(child=serializers.CharField())
    ...
```